# Why OpenSSH client is not using my keys on Windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, openssh

I'm on Windows 10, using an OpenSSH client to connect to a Debian server.
All my keys are stored in `C:\Users\entityinarray\.ssh\`

```
PS C:\Users\entityinarray> ssh root@192.168.1.100
root@192.168.1.100: Permission denied (publickey).
PS C:\Users\entityinarray> ssh root@192.168.1.100 -o IdentityFile=~\.ssh\id_okcomputer
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\entityinarray/\.ssh\id_okcomputer':
Linux okserver 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Feb  7 09:55:39 2024 from 192.168.1.2
root@okserver:~#
```

Passing down `IdentityFile=~\.ssh\id_okcomputer` works! But I want it to find keys automatically.
My `~\.ssh\config`:

```
Host example.com
  HostName example.com
  Port 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_okcomputer

Host radio.example.com
  HostName radio.example.com
  Port 2022
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_okcomputer

Host linux-gaming
  HostName 123.123.123.123
  Port 22
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_okcomputer
```

Comment: One reason probably would be in your key file isn’t in the correct location. Provide the verbose client logs.

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying `192.168.1.100` as the SSH hostname but you have no `Host 192.168.1.100` section in your ~/.ssh/config. The only sections you have in there are for different hosts entirely.

If you want a parameter such as `IdentityFile` to apply to all hosts, put it in a `Host *` section (which should be at the end, below the more-specific matches).

Comment: Thank you! However, while I was on Linux, it was picking necessary keys from ~/.ssh on its own. IdentityFile only allows to specify a single key file, not folder of keys. Is there a way to make ssh automatically pick necessary keys from a folder like it does on Linux?

Comment: No. Even on Linux, it doesn't scan the whole folder – it only looks for id_rsa, id_ecdsa, id_ed25519, and that's it. (Maybe GNOME Keyring was autoloading the other keys for you?) If you have multiple keys, you can list all of them in the option, or you can load them into ssh-agent where ssh will use them automatically.